# Export an inherited process in Devops via APIs

Tags: api, azure-devops

I would like to export an inherited process in Devops via APIs. I found this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processadmin/processes/export-process-template?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP)

But after calling this API, I recieve the following response:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "The feature is disabled. Contact your Azure DevOps Server administrator.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.FeatureDisabledException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server",
    "typeKey": "FeatureDisabledException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 3000
}
```

It sounds to me, to achieve this aim something should be enabled.

Does any one know what should I enable and in which place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not available for the Inherited process. You may use it for [On-premises XML process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/on-premises-xml-process-model?view=azure-devops-2022).

Available APIs for the inherited processes you may find here: [Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/processes?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).